# Gradle Plugin downloads its own dependencies?

Tags: gradle

I'm a Gradle newb and I'm moving a large build over to Gradle from Maven. I find that I need to write a plugin. Specifically, something to handle drools. How can I write a plugin that downloads its own dependencies so that my users don't have to mess with that? Ideally this would be over-ridable so that my user doesn't necessarily get stuck with those automatically downloaded libraries.

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do here.  You publish your plugin just like any other Java lib, and its ivy/pom.xml describes its transitive dependencies.  Gradle will then automatically pull them in if the user declares it on their buildscript classpath.

Comment: My point is that the user shouldn't have to do that by default every time. If my project has dependencies why can't I make them transitive so that the user need not include them because I already have?

Comment: That is exactly what @OliverCharlesworth is describing.

Comment: @user447607 - Yes, Gradle does this automatically.